# Importing Massive text file into a sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am currently trying to import a text file with 180+ million records with about 300+ columns into my sql server database. Needless to say the file is roughly 70 GBs large. I have been at it for days and when i get close something happens and it craps out on me. I need the quickest and most efficient way to do this import. I have tried the wizard which should have been the easiest, then i tried just saving as an ssis package. I havent been able to figure out how to do a bulk import with the settings i think would work great. The error i keep on getting is 'not enough virtual memory'. I changed my virtual memory to 36 gigs .  My system has 24 gigs of physical memory. Please help me.

Comment: If you haven't already tried, you almost certainly want to use the "bcp" bulk copy too, or "bulk insert" T-SQL extension: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx.  You should also read this article: [Optimizing Bulk Import Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  That includes dropping indexes, minimizing logging, etc.

Comment: can you break it into pieces? I use a program called LTFViewer (Large Text File) for those massive text files and it seems to be able to handle them.  Then import the smaller chunks one at a time or with an SSIS package for each loop.

Comment: I tried chopping it into pieces, but then i run into where a couple of pieces dont have the same number of columns. The first one will have all 364 columns but then another part will have only 11 or 12 columns

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BCP (and you should be for files this large), use a batch size. Otherwise, BCP will attempt to load all records in one transaction.

By command line: `bcp -b 1000`

By C#:

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = 
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000; // 1000 rows
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable); // May also pass in DataRow[]
}
```

Here are the highlights from [this MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188267%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Importing a large data file as a single batch can be problematic, so
>   bcp and BULK INSERT let you import data in a series of batches, each
>   of which is smaller than the data file. Each batch is imported and
>   logged in a separate transaction...

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the maximum server memory for SQL Server to as low as you can get away with. (Right click the SQL instance in Mgmt Studio -> properties -> memory).

This may free up enough memory for the OS & SSIS to process such a big text file.

I'm assuming the whole process is happening locally on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with SQL 2012 and trying to import (as a test) around 7 million records into a database.  I too ran out of memory and had to cut the bulk import into smaller pieces.  The one thing to note is that all the memory that the import process uses (no matter what manner you leverage) up a ton of memory and won't release said system memory until the server was rebooted.  I'm not sure if this is intended behavior by SQL Server but it's something to note for your project.

Because I was using the SEQUENCE command with this process I had to leverage T-sql code saved as sql scripts and then use SQLCMD in small pieces to lessen the memory overhead.

You'll have to play around with what works for you and highly recommend to not run the script all at once.

It's going to be a pain in the ass to break it down in smaller pieces and import it in but in the long run you'll be happier.